# How to tie knot for adjustable string strumstick strap

Tags: instruments, maintenance

I have a strumstick and part of the requirement to hold it comfortably for playing is to have the string that's used for a strap adjusted to the correct length. The way they do this is with a special slip knot in the rope that makes it so that you can tighten the string but then hold tension on the knot in its position while you play.

Unfortunately when I first got the strumstick I didn't realized this and untied the string. Then when I re-tied it I used a regular slip knot and it's constantly slipping on me!

I can't find anything particular online that would help me. I thought about tying the slipnot with a different "feed" source but that would create a long dangling string that I don't see other strumstick players with.

So does anyone know how to tie the strap for a strumstick properly?

Comment: Have you tried a tautline hitch? http://www.netknots.com/rope_knots/tautline-hitch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer just so there is one for future Googlers, even if the links disappear...

Two alternatives for slipknots that stay fast under load are the [Tautline Hitch](http://www.netknots.com/rope_knots/tautline-hitch/) & [Midshipman's Hitch](http://www.netknots.com/rope_knots/midshipmans-hitch)

---

**Tautline Hitch**

[image]

---

**Midshipman's Hitch**

[image]

Comment: Your picture links are dead.

Comment: @Dom - they are [or were] on stack exchange's i.imgur, so maybe they were subject to takedown. The page links still work to the originals - I just didn't want it to be a link-only answer, but I don't feel comfortable re-inserting the images, just in case.